# During a period of time "I get better" or "I'm getting" better?

Tags: grammar

As title, which one is more correct between:

- It seems this month I'm getting better at something
- It seems this month I get better at something

Or maybe both are grammatically correct, are just different in what they mean.?

Comment: Possible similarity to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308551/which-of-the-two-is-grammatically-correct
Running currently among the questions. See the linked questions in that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before some certain people come in claiming that one is valid and one isn't,
I'd like to say that both are grammatically correct, but the second example is less common and more general in meaning.

- [It seems] this month [I'm getting better] [at something].

  Arguably this month is a "replacement" for that, and more specific in meaning.
- [It seems that I'm getting better at something]

  To outside viewers i'm improving my own capabilities of doing something, actively participating.
- [It seems that I get better at something]

  Almost the same initially, but can lack the active participation, as in, someone "suffers" getting better at something. Or in a broader view, someone receives something that is called better, somewhere(at something).

Without more context:
***They do mean the same thing, and both are grammatically correct.***